# Why are the words Kiddushin, Erusin, Nissuin plural?

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk, wedding

The Mishnah says "האיש מקדש", just like on Shabbos. Nevertheless, on Shabbos we call it a Kiddush (single) but on wedding we call it either Kiddushin, Erusin, Nissuin which are all plural.

Comment: Finding sources that use these respectively plural and singular terms, would improve the question.

Comment: Do you mean "why are the words in the plural" or "why do we use the plural out of the plural context, when referring to a singular concept?'

Comment: I don't think there is anything more to this than it just being a "group name" that has a plural ending but is still singular. It refers to the subject or concept itself. Like saying "marriages", "engagements", etc. A person has one marriage or engagement at a time, but the word doesn't apply to the individual, it applies to the general subject or concept.

Comment: Isn't it simply because the three examples mentioned are instances of two people? The noun is referring to the ceremony which always has two, as opposed to the verb "מקדש".

Comment: Ybum is never plural, ybumin ... I do not remember. There is yabamim but it is something else, kidushe kesef, Hupa is also never plural. Very good question.

Comment: Also Geirushin is always in the plural.

Comment: A man can experience only one shabbat at a time (thereby kiddush is singular), but a man can experience more than one wife at a time (thereby kiddushin etc. is plural). I am not trying to be funny, but serious. If I am wrong or right, please quote a rabbinic source that says the same thing or an opposing thing I just hereby wrote.

Comment: @DanF "A person has one marriage or engagement at a time". Can not a man get married to two women at the same time? It says in 2 Chronicles 24:3 וַיִּשָּׂא־ל֥וֹ יְהֽוֹיָדָ֖ע נָשִׁ֣ים שְׁתָּ֑יִם.

Answer (score 4):

[R. Yissakhar Tamar](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A8_%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%A8) addresses the term kiddushin in Alei Tamar to Yerushalmi Berakhot (2:3), and his explanation answers erusin as well.

He explains that the plural expression references the three ways that kiddushin can be performed (cf. Kiddushin 1:1). However, he notes that Teimanim traditionally referred to it in the singular.[i]

It should be noted that this explanation probably does not address nissuin though.

---

[i] Lest anyone ask that the tractate is called 'Kiddushin', that is like 'Pesahim', the korban is still called a 'Pesah'. So too, the tractate refers to marriages, but individual ones are referred to as 'kiddush'.

Comment: One example left out of the OP which this doesn’t explain either is Geirushin.

Comment: Aren't there multiple ways to perform nisuin? Chuppah is one, as well as biah. Also if chuppah doesn't mean yichud gamur, yichud gamur also should work (Taz EH 55:2)

Comment: @robev I thought that essentially only huppa works. The question is, what is huppa. This would be similar to kiddushei kessef which can use many forms of money. But I was unsure.

Comment: At the very least Kesubos 48b mentions two types of nisuin: נכנסה לחופה ולא נבעלה and נישואין ממש which Rashi says means נבעלה

Comment: @robev But aren't those two iterations of the concept of huppa. (Part of why I didn't get into it, is that it is somewhat of  a semantic question. One could argue that all forms of kiddush have some conceptual similarity, and are themselves just different iterations).

Comment: Nice try, but it does not hold for all other, like Kinyan that can be performed in mamy ways, Hakdesh, Maaser, Shabbes Kiddush etc. Could be a tirutz, but does not explain it.

Comment: @al no idea what you are talking about. It address kiddushin and nissuin. And notes that the term is likely kiddish not kiddushin anyway. There is no reason a priori to assume that a single distinction would explain every phenomenon mentioned or not mentioned, in your likely too broad question.

Answer (score 0):

Kiddush means Havdolo(separation).Rashi says in Bereishis 2,3 on the word וַיְקַדֵּשׁ -קדשו במן שלא ירד כלל בשבת - Hashem separated Shabbos from the rest of the week by not making the manna fall at all on shabbos in contrast to the rest of the week where it did fall.

On shabos You are doing one separation between a Chol weekday, and a Kodesh Shabbos this is indicated in the Brocho where we say Mekadesh Hashabbos (note that Ki vonu bocharto.. micol hoamim is in brackets and some people don't say it for this very reason that we are mainly marking the difference between Shabbos and Chol, other separations are subordinate. This would also explain why in havdala [singular] that even though there are 4 separations, the preeminent separation is between Shabbat and Chol).

This is 1 division

At a kidushin there are numerous divisions, because through marrying a women That man becomes separted (see Vayikra chapter 18 for the list)i.e biblicly forbiden to:
1. her mother,
2.her Mother's mother
3.her Father's Mother
4.her daughter(s)
5.her Son's daughter(s)
6.her daughters daughter(s)
7. Her sister(s)
8. He's Rabbinically forbidden to the Bride until she enters his domicile (i.e chuppa).

She is also forbiddon to everyone in the world like Hekdesh.

So we see 9 different separations: 8 on the mans side and 1 separation to an entity(which includes all men including the husband who is rabbically forbidden to her until she enters his domicile) on the womans side.

This is indicated in the Brocho (kesubos 7b) ברכת האירוסין מאי מברך רבין בר רב אדא ורבה בר רב אדא תרוייהו משמיה דרב יהודה אמרי בא"י אמ"ה אשר קדשנו במצותיו וצונו **על העריות ואסר לנו את הארוסות** והתיר לנו את הנשואות על ידי חופה 
וקדושין - Arayos are new forbidddon relationships that are biblically forbiddon,  arusos are the man and woman who are rabbically forbiddon to each other until she enters his domicile.

"האיש מקדש" is singular because he is only one man (we're not dealing with many men betrothing simultaniously). But he can sanctify (separate) many things at once e.g  האיש מקדש את אשתו ואת עצמו מן אמה אם אביה בתה בת בתה

Eirusin is plural because it means 2 things are happening the husband is betrothed to the woman and the woman is betrothed to the man, result being they are both ossur to each other as it says ואסר לנו את הארוסות.

Nissuin is plural because it means 2 things are happening the husband is permitted (i.e the prohibition is lifted of himself) to the woman and the woman is permitted to the man, result being they are both permitted to each other. Nissuin litterally means lifting off oneself (the prohibition of being together from the time of betrothal) as it says famously in Tashlich from micha 7,19 מִי אֵל כָּמוֹךָ נֹשֵׂא עָו‍ֹן - Who is G-d like You who lifts off sin from upon us.

Comment: Thank you for a long answer, but I don't see any connection. Only one woman is מקודשת to him, not the relatives, as relatives are allowed to their spouses, as the Gemmorah says "she's forbidden to the whole world". I could not also understand your hint in the Berocho - אסר לנו את הארוסות - we all know, once woman is מאורסת she's forbidden to all. My point is, all those words are plural, inc Nisuin.

Comment: its nice to have feedback from the questioner.what i am trying to say is that the word kiddushin means many separations, had he not betrothed this woman, he could have betrothed her mother (assuming she wasn't married at the time), or her grandmother, or daughter etc. Now that he chose this women, even if he divorces her, her mother grandmother and daughter who are also unmarried are forbidden to him forever (exception sister who is permitted after death of wife). So we see he has many new mitzvos of separations which never applied before. i hope this sounds clear.

Comment: Interesting. Is it your own idea? Otherwise, can you edit into the answer post a citation of your source?

Comment: @user15464. I replied 2 days ago. **First, Kiddushin is not "separation", but "dedication"**. Once something is dedicated it is automatically separated from other uses. Here, there's no dedication for wife's relatives. They are not "re-dedicated", and not "separated", they are allowed to others. **Second, you answer does not explain other languages - Erusin and Nissuin**.

Comment: By this logic, why don’t we say that when a person buys an object he performs קנינין, rather than קנין, since the object, previously forbidden to him, is now permissible, and still forbidden to the rest of the world? Also, why do we refer to the prohibitions when discussing these acquisitions - would it not make more sense to discuss the fact that she is now becoming *his* wife rather than her inability to become someone else’s wife, or his inability for certain people to become his wife?

Comment: DonielF, you are right that when the man aquires the woman only one aquisition takes place hence the mishna in kiddushin 2a says "Ha-isha nikneis" in the singular,which is the what makes her become his wife. Kiddushin (the many separations) is simultanius to the one aquisition he makes by giving his wife shave pruta to Aquire her.

Comment: (If you preface my name with @, you’ll ping me, which would let me know much sooner that you’ve responded to me.) I didn’t say anything about one acquisition or multiple acquisitions. I don’t see how this answers my question at all; if the point is multiple prohibitions on other people, then we should use a similar terminology by ordinary acquisitions, as it forbids others from using it while permitting his usage. It also doesn’t answer the OP’s question of the word קדש meaning dedication for a specific usage - not dedicating oneself to not be used in a certain way.

Comment: (Con’t) The term Kiddushin comes from the word Hekdesh (Kiddushin 2b). As Rashi explains (s.v. d’asar lah), the connection is either that she is sanctified for his behalf, the way that a Karban is sanctified for Heaven, or that she is dedicated to him the way a Karban is dedicated to Heaven. He does conclude that this is a dedication that prohibits her to others, so one could not say that a Talis is mekudash to him. However, the focus is still on the dedication, not the prohibition.

Comment: @DonielF kiddushin is a permanent status that a human can't change without following the torahs blue print to release her e.g  giving her a Get, and her mother the Torah prohibits permenantly as there is no clause of release. A regular aquisition is only prohibited to others for benefit when the owner is makpid, e.g someone he doesn't know steals, but that same person when given permission is not prohibitted from the Torah. So a kinyan just means that the item is subject to that 1 person who is the owner to decide whether just he, other people, or everyone can benefit from his item

Comment: @AlBerko you are mistaken that **קדש in this context  does not mean dedidication** as it does with regards to a prostitute (e.g bereishis 38). This kiddushin separates her from **everyone** including her husband as indicated in kesubos 7b quoted in my answer. this is why this woman is comparable to  הקדש in kiddushin 2b דאסר לה אכולי עלמא כהקדש she is Ossur to everyone like hekdesh which is itself ossur to everyone before the blood is thrown/poured on the Mizbeah

Comment: @DonielF see what i wrote in previous note

Comment: @DonielF I had a second thought, Kiddushin does not come from Hakdesh (I know the Gemmora). THat would be Hakdeshim as it comes from Binyan Heph'il, not Piel. Kiddushin comes from Kiddush (Lekadesh), wich is Piel. So Gemmora's answer is just a Tirutz. It's like Karov (Krova) from Lekarev, Kadosh from Lekadesh and so  on. THe saying goes "Herey at Mekudeshes" which stems from Lekadesh not Lahakdish.

Comment: @user15464 So you’re arguing on Rashi now?

Comment: @DonielF , im not arguing with Rashi as קָדֵשׁ which has differrent vows means dedicated as rashi says מזומן למשכב זכור- dedicated for prostitution, in Devarim 23,18. Rashi says in Bereishis 2,3 on the word וַיְקַדֵּשׁ  -קדשו במן שלא ירד כלל בשבת - Hashem separated Shabbos from the rest of the week by not making the manna fall at all on shabbos in contrast to the rest of the week where it did fall. The gemora kiddushin indicates that the woman is "separated" from everyone like rashi in bereishis, not dedicated like a  like Devarim 23,18.

Comment: I didn’t ask what Rashi said elsewhere. I’m describing what Rashi says on the Gemara in question.

Comment: @user15464 Read my earlier comment quoting Rashi again and get back to me

Comment: @DonielF why dont you look  for yourself kiddushin 2b http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=2b&format=pdf  your rashi doesn't exist

Comment: @user15464 Okay, I see what happened. Sefaria has it as Rashi. https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Kiddushin.2b.2. In that Tzuras HaDaf you posted, it’s Tosfos, same divrei hamaschil.

Comment: does that mean you will ever give me a point? I hope you are not offended from my language if you want i can delete that part of the conversation